# set default value to field in customer information form

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento2.2

I'm using **Magento 1.6.2** and I have a function that create a random **unique email address** placed at

`app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\form\renderer\fieldset\element.phtml.`

It's value set by default in email field when I create a new customer from Admin by adding that on `elemant.phtml`. Now I'm moving to magento 2 and looking for that page location on magento 2 so I can put the random uniqe email address and set the value once I click on add new customer. Any solution?